# Android listen to service listeners while app in background

Tags: android

I have a `Service` that implements `MediaPlayer.onCompleteListener` and when I am with my app in background the `listener` doesn't trigger as it should when I am in app. I did try to search something about this subject but no clue how to fix it.
When the `completeListener` is triggering I want the `MediaPlayer` to pass to the next song. I am starting the service in activity and make it foreground with a notification.

My service class is the following:

```
public class PlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener{

    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "action.PLAY";
    private static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "action.PAUSE";
    private static final String ACTION_RESUME = "action.RESUME";
    private static final String ACTION_SEEK = "action.SEEK_TO";
    private static final String ACTION_NEXT = "action.NEXT";
    private static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "action.PREVIOUS";
    private static final String ACTION_REPEAT = "action.REPEAT";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private String curentURL;
    private boolean repeat = false;
    private int currentPosition;

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("TEST", "Primesc comanda prin BroadcastReceiver " + intent.getAction());
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals(ACTION_PLAY)){
                curentURL = intent.getStringExtra("musicURL");
                currentPosition = intent.getIntExtra("musicPosition", 0);
                try {
                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(intent.getStringExtra("musicURL"));
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(action.equals(ACTION_PAUSE)){
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else if(action.equals(ACTION_RESUME)){
                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            } else if(action.equals(ACTION_SEEK)){
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(intent.getIntExtra("seekProgress", 0) * 100);
                Log.i("TEST","Dau seek la "+intent.getIntExtra("seekProgress", 0));
            } else if(action.equals(ACTION_NEXT)){
                Intent nextIntent = new Intent("action.activity.NEXT");
                intent.putExtra("nextPosition", currentPosition+1);
                sendBroadcast(nextIntent);
            } else if(action.equals(ACTION_PREVIOUS)){
                Intent previousIntent = new Intent("action.activity.PREVIOUS");
                intent.putExtra("previousPosition", currentPosition-1);
                sendBroadcast(previousIntent);
            } else if(action.equals(ACTION_REPEAT)) {
                repeat = intent.getBooleanExtra("repeatStatus", false);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_PLAY);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_NEXT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_RESUME);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_SEEK);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_REPEAT);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.playlisticon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, musicPlayer.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
                getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
        startForeground(1337, notification);

        Log.i("TEST","onCreate se apeleaza");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i("TEST","A pornit service-ul");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("TEST", "Se face onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();

        Intent intent = new Intent("action.activity.UPDATE_UI");
        intent.putExtra("duration", mp.getDuration());
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Log.i("TEST", "Eroare incerc din nou "+what+" "+extra);

        try {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(curentURL);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.i("TEST", "Action onComplete");

        if(repeat) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("action.activity.REPEAT");
            intent.putExtra("currentPosition", currentPosition);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent("action.activity.NEXT");
            intent.putExtra("nextPosition", currentPosition+1);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            Intent intent = new Intent("action.activity.UPDATE_BUFFER");
            intent.putExtra("progress", percent);
            intent.putExtra("seekBarProgress", mp.getCurrentPosition() / 100);
            intent.putExtra("mediaCurentPosition", mp.getCurrentPosition());
            sendBroadcast(intent);

            Log.i("TEST","Current Position = "+mp.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want your app to do with the listener event if it's backgrounded, and where are you registering this listener?  There's no UI to update, so it'd have to be an operation that only another Service can do.

Comment: Sorry, I realised after, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

This might help .....  you may want to add this code in manifest

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.audioManager">   
      <intent-filter>
         <action   android:name="android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener" />         
      </intent-filter>

   </receiver>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: it is just registering receiver in your manifest.... without registering your receiver it will not work.